# What is the typescript equivalent for Asynchronous action in Redux-toolkit

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit

I am trying to add typescript to redux toolkit app. This is a simple counter app, to increase or decrease the counter state by one.

```js
import {
  createSlice,
  Dispatch,
  PayloadAction
} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export interface CounterState {
  value: number;
};

const initialState: CounterState = {
  value: 0
};

export const counterSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'Counter Slice',
  initialState: initialState,
  reducers: {
    increment: (state) => {
      state.value = state.value + 1;
    },
    decrement: (state) => {
      state.value = state.value - 1;
    },
    incrementByAmount: (state, action: PayloadAction < number > ) => {
      state.value = state.value + action.payload;
    }
  }
});

//What would be the type of "incrementAsync"
export const incrementAsync: any = (amount: number) => (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    dispatch(incrementByAmount(amount));
  }, 1000);
};

export const {
  increment,
  decrement,
  incrementByAmount
} = counterSlice.actions;
export default counterSlice.reducer;
```

What should be the type annotation for `incrementAsync` instead of the `any` type I have used just to make it work. The official redux toolkit documentation didn't help me.

The `incrementAsync` is just using a timeout function to increase the counter value by one after a delay of one second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a type annotation there - TypeScript already knows very well that

```
(amount: number) => (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    dispatch(incrementByAmount(amount));
  }, 1000);
};
```

is of the type

```
(amount: number) => (dispatch: Dispatch) => void
```

.

You don't need to write that down and don't need an alias for that - it will work nicely with Redux already. Just skip the manual type annotation on your `const`.

You can use an `AppThunk` type as described in [Type Checking Redux Thunks](https://redux.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#type-checking-redux-thunks), but there is not a lot of benefit to it and tbh., I find it more difficult to handle.

Or you go, as already suggested in the other answer, with `createAsyncThunk`, but you only should do that if you have something that really needs a lifecicle, so a "pending" action before and a "fulfilled" or "rejected" action afterwards.

Comment: Argument of type '(dispatch: Dispatch) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'.
  Property 'type' is missing in type '(dispatch: Dispatch) => void' but required in type 'AnyAction'.              I am getting this error when I removed the "any" type inference. Also, thank you for the help.

Comment: That is because your `dispatch` is typed incorrectly, not your thunk. For that, please follow the [TypeScript QuickStart](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/typescript), especially the part about typed hooks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use [`createAsyncThunk()`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk). Together with TypeScript this can look like this:

```js
export const incrementAsync = createAsyncThunk<void, number>(
  "counter/incrementAsync",
  async (amount, { dispatch }) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      dispatch(incrementByAmount(amount))
    }, 1000)
  }
)
```

That way your function `incrementAsync` is typed via inferring the type from the function `createAsyncThunk()`

Reference for [`createAsyncThunk` together with TypeScript](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#createasyncthunk)